# Regex get all image when word is not in source

Tags: php, regex

I have some description for our products, but sadly, this is a legacy code, and there is a lot of html elements, what I really do not need. I remove these with `strip_tags` but I need to keep images. Unfortunatly, the previous deisgn what is so old, contained strings after strip like this:

```
<IMG border=0 alt="" src="http:///Images/white.gif" width=5 height=1>
<IMG border=0 alt="" src="http:///Images/white.gif" width=170 height=1>

<img  src="/asdsa/alkatreszkepek/aasdsa.jpg">

<IMG border=0 alt="" src="http:///Images/white.gif" width=170 height=1>

<IMG border=0 alt="" src="http:///Images/white.gif" width=2 height=1>
```

I need to replace all the images, what not contains `alkatreszkepek` (means product picutres) in the src tags.

What I tried so far:

first get only one image:

```
<img.*?src=".*?".*?>
```

Cool, so I am using `isg` modifiers, it is found all images.

Now I am try to negate:

```
<img.*?src=".*?^(?!.alkatreszkepek).*?".*?>
```

but in this case nothing will be selected.

Can somebody help me, how te get all those unnecessary images?

I want to `preg_replace` them to nothing in PHP.

**EDIT**

Yes, I know, I could get all images with `preg_match_all` , then iterate through on the matches, and easily `str_replace` them I just want to know, how can I do it with regex.

Comment: Try `<img[^<]*?\bsrc="(?![^"<]*?alkatreszkepek)[^"<]*"[^<]*?>`

Comment: Can't you parse that all with a DOM parser?

Comment: Currently I am using my `str_replace` version. freedev solution is ok for us too, because there is no `alt="alkatreszkepek"` in any image like this.  But now I am just getting curiois.

Comment: More or less safe regex is above in my first comment. https://regex101.com/r/yP4kX8/1 but why regex?

Comment: Talking about regex and html, I love this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags,

Comment: @freedev Cool post, you are right, now I am get it why ya'll suggested DOM parser.

Comment: @karacsi_maci yep, hope you read first answer. It is superb, the guy who wrote that was really inspired :)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (not very efficient though):

```
(?:<img[^>]+src\s*=\s*(["'])(((?!alkatreszkepek).)*?))\1[^>]*>
```

The regex above will match any img, not containing the (sub) string 'alkatreszkepek' inside src attribute (handling different quotes `"` or `'` )

This version in group #2 matches the image url

Tested here: https://regex101.com/r/dE5vS7/8

Comment: No, again, does not - https://regex101.com/r/dE5vS7/5. Only those `img` should be failed that have `alkatreszkepek` in the `src` attribute.

Comment: What if the `alt` that is before `src` contains a `>`? Then it won't work again.

Comment: Oh my god guys, you are regex mages :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have updated my answer, version 8 handles different quote type, and returns the image url in group #2